# How to stop laravel schedule:run on local computer in Windows 10

Tags: php, laravel, scheduled-tasks

I am using **laravel version 9.52** and today I was trying to run a scheduled task. Instead of typing **schedule:work** I typed in **schedule:run**. I am afraid that I have started a scheduler to run on my local computer and now I am not able to figure out how to stop it again.

I am using **Vagrant homestead** on **Windows 10**.

Tried to type in crontab -l but I get "no crontab for vagrant"

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You could try to find the command in `top` or `htop`. then kill the pid if you find it

Comment: `schedule:run` just checks if there is anything due to run at the time you run it and then terminates. It's intended to run via a scheduler every minute. Running it in the command line doesn't really do anything in the background (unless there's an actual task that is due to run when you run it)

Comment: @IGP I tried to htop but It only runs for a few seconds and then removes itself. I

Comment: @apokryfos I started my machine some minutes ago and without typing the schedule:run command it still runs the tasks added to my scheduler. I am not sure if this is the intended way from laravel but I've always had to type the command schedule:work before any task gets processed. Unfortunately I typed in schedule:run this time and it seems to run forever.

Comment: Running `schedule:run` does not make it start as a service. Check windows scheduler if you have anything scheduled to run this command. Also check `/etc/crontab` and any files in `/etc/cron.d` in your VM for anything scheduled in there

Comment: @apokryfos can you explain how to check /etc/crontab in VM ?

Comment: In the VM running `cat /etc/crontab` should show you the root user's crontab (similarly to how `crontab -l` shows you the current user's crontab). Since homestead is a prepackaged laravel environment it's likely it comes with the scheduler pre-setup

Comment: @apokryfos running cat /etc/crontab shows four anacron jobs running: cron.hourly, cron.daily, cron.weekly and cron.monthly. are they related to laravel in some way?

Answer (score 3):

`php artisan schedule:run` should end immediatly after the task queue has been processed, instead `php artisan schedule:work` stays active until you kill it

Comment: Artisan schedule:work should stop when typing ctrl+c and I did that. When typing schedule:list I can see that the jobs are waiting to be executed. I restarted my computer and tried to see if it stopped but it did not

Comment: @Rorabih yes, doing so you send killing signal `'SIGINT'` (interrupt from the keyboard) to the process, and you kill it.

Comment: can you explain how to do that in steps? I am not familiar with this

Comment: @Rorabih `php artisan schedule::list` shows the jobs that you set to be executed, but if a worker is not running they are not started

Comment: In my case they are being executed without a worker. I restarted my computer, typed vagrant up, vagrant ssh and they are executed. Without me typing schedule:work